# ExtJS Handling Response Holding PDF as StreamingOutput

Tags: java, ajax, extjs, response

I am working with extJS 4.2.1 and I would like to display a PDF file that is stored in a ResponseBuilder as a StreamingOutput object. When the response is returned to the extjs controller, Im not sure how to handle it in order to display the PDF on a new page.

```
@GET
@Path("/images/{imageNumber}/{imageType}")
@Produces({"application/pdf"})
public Response openDocument(@PathParam("company") String company, 
@PathParam("imageNumber") String imageNumber, @PathParam("imageType") String imageType){

final File imageFile = new File("/someRemoteDir/28717484.pdf");
StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {

public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
try {
  InputStream input = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
  byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
  int c = 0;
  while ((c = input.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, c);
                    output.flush();
  }
  output.close();
  input.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
};

ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(stream);
response.type("application/pdf");
response.status(200);
response.header("Accept-Ranges","bytes");
response.header("Cache-Control",null);
response.header("Pragma",null);
response.header("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"" + imageDoc.getNumber() +"\"");
return response.build();
}
```

extJS controller

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: CTrack.Config.appPath('loads/images/' + imageNumber + '/' + imageType),
  jsonSubmit: true,
  success: function(response, opt) {
    if (response.status == 200) {
       NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE?.........
    } else {
        me.displayError(errorMsg);
    } },
  failure: function(response, opt) { 
    console.log('Failure');
  }
```

...

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually do this. I would just have an iframe and set the src to be the URL you've defined above.

Comment: well I would be this file will not be local to the system.